# Word 2007 VBA wildcard for inline picture or shape

Tags: image, graphics, wildcard, word-2007

All the search results say it is `^g`: This code returns message "^g is not a valid special character for the find what box or is not supported when the use wildcard is check box is ticked"

They also say that `^1` is the code for "picture or graphic (in-line only)": this code does not find inline pictures in word 2007.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is "/".
eg `(/)(^13)` in find box will find any picture followed by a paragraph mark (and group to replace only 1 of them).

in VBA replace macro `"(/)(^13)"`